# How do I turn iMessages off in OS X?

Tags: macos, messages

How do I turn iMessages off on my MacBook? I have tried to go to settings but those were in the old version! I don't know how to turn it off in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments already, within Messages go to `Preferences > Accounts` and highlight the iMessage account.  There either untick the box for Enable this account or sign out of iMessage, which will effectively disable the account.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the version of OS X is 10.10 (Yosemite):

Go to `System Preferences` and click `Internet Accounts`.

Choose an appropriate account, and deselect `Messages` from the list of selected applications.

Comment: I don't see Messages in that pref - everything else iCloud-related but not Messages. iMessage sign & out is in the Messages app prefs itself, accounts tab. Uncheck Enable this account.

Comment: This only works if disabling messages for Google, AIM, (supported internet acct. with messaging service), but *not* for iMessage. As @Tetsujin mentioned, disabling the latter must be done in the Messages.app itself.